# Changing the contents of a div using a dropdown, javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, function, drop-down-menu

I'm a noob but will gladly take some stick for it if you help me find the answer ;)

I have a list of categories in an array $cat_array.
I want to build a select drop-down so that when I select one of the options, a different variable is passed to a function.

This is what I have so far:
In the main file (index.php), I call a function:

```
makechoice($cat_array);
```

This refers to this function which is in an included file:

```
function makechoice($cat_array) {   
$dbz = new db();
$sim = new simple();
echo '<div class="choose-section">';
    echo '<select class="selbox" onchange="categoryAjaxData(\'facebook\',\'/includes/fancount.php\',this.value);">';
        foreach($cat_array as $cat) {   
            echo('<option value="'.$cat[0].'">'.$cat[1].'</option>');   
        }
    echo '</select>';
    echo 'Choose a section';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($djnames, $djids, $djurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
}
```

In includes/fancount.php, I have basically have lots of different variables that I want to pass through the showfans function.

e.g. $barnames, $barids, $barurl & $restaurantname, $restaurantids, $restauranturl

The showfans function uses these variables to display some data about them.

This is my javascript code:

```
function categoryAjaxData(div,str,value)
{
    var url = str+'?catid='+value;
    ajaxData(div,url);
}

function ajaxData(div,str)
    {
        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML='<center><img src="images/loader.gif"></center>';        
        if(xmlHttp==null)
        {
            alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
            return
        }
            var url = str;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){ DescriptionstateChanged(div); };
            xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

function DescriptionstateChanged(div)
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    {
        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

AT THE MOMENT: 
The content in the current facebook div reloads, I can see the loader - but I'm stuck with how to  link the option selected in the select dropdown to changing the variables in the showfans() function.

E.g. 
I want "Bar" in the dropdown to show:

```
echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($barnames, $barids, $barurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
```

I want "Restaurant" in the dropdown to show:

```
echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($restaurantnames, $restaurantids, $restauranturl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
```

I hope that helps! Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE:

With regards to fancount.php, I have been looking at various different options - but I can't seem to get any of them to work!

I want to pass the value from the dropdown into a logic so that depending on the varlue chosen, certain variables are used by showfans() and the output code looks similar to this for the various combination of variables:

echo '',showfans($restaurantnames, $restaurantids, $restauranturl),'';

Answer (score 1):

n00b! OK, stick out of the way :-)

You are passing `'facebook-midcut'` to your `categoryAjaxData()` function.  Does the eventual DOM lookup know whether you mean the div with the id or the div with that class? If you're using a libray like jquery it wouldn't know which node you mean without further classification.  I would guess you're trying to get the one with the class so you can't use `getElementById()`.

You may also want to add a slash to the start of `'includes/fancount.php'`.  Adding a slash to the start of this means the path will reference from your site's document root rather than from your current location within the site.

Are you using some kind of js library? It would be useful to see your ajaxData function as the problem could very well be there.

A quick tip for you.  Learn when to use single and double quotes in PHP.  It will make your code simpler and faster. `echo "<div id=\"facebook-midcut\">";` could be written as `echo '<div id="facebook-midcut">';`

I'll check back to see if you've updated your post with the info I've asked for then I can give you more help.

UPDATE:

I assume the function `DescriptionstateChanged(div)` is where the actual updating of the div happens but you never pass it the xmlHttp object.  Is this meant to be a global object?  If not then you definitely need to pass it to the `DescriptionstateChanged()` function and I would recommend that it shouldn't be a global object anyway.  If the `DescriptionstateChanged()` function is where the actual updating of the div takes place can you post this function too?

Comment: Updated with the ajaxData function :)

Comment: I have also edited the post with the echo '<div id="facebook-midcut">'

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change this:

```
echo '<select class="selbox" onchange="categoryAjaxData("facebook-midcut","/includes/fancount.php",this.value);">';
```

with this:

```
echo '<select class="selbox" onchange="categoryAjaxData(\'facebook-midcut\',\'/includes/fancount.php\',this.value);">';
```

Note how the output of your code would be invalid HTML:

```
<select class="selbox" onchange="categoryAjaxData("facebook-midcut","/includes/fancount.php",this.value);">
```

Comment: Hello Mario, thank you :) I changed from double quotes as per the first comment and missed those. Have you any idea how to solve the drop-down problem? I want to get the dropdown to pass a different value to the function showfans();

Comment: If you post the code for `/includes/fancount.php` it will be easier to help you...

Comment: I have tried a number of things in founcount.php however, I cannot seem to pass the variable by javascript. Sorry Mario, I have been looking at this problem all day and have been hacking away at the code so much that that what I had 6 hours ago doesn't look the same...