# How to pass the value of a <select> drop-down list to function in another file using javascript

Tags: php, ajax, function, variables, select

FIXED; it was a case of adding another include into the fancount.php file!

Initial code:

```
<div class="l-title">
<div class="t-left"></div>
<div class="t-mid">Popularity Update</div>
<div class="t-right"></div></div>
<?php makechoice($cat_array); ?>
```

Function code:

```
function makechoice($cat_array) {   
        global $djnames;
        global $djids;
        global $djurl;
        $dbz = new db();
        $sim = new simple();
        echo '<div class="choose-section">';
            echo '<select class="selbox" onchange="categoryAjaxData(\'facebook\',\'/includes/fancount.php\',this.value);">';
                foreach($cat_array as $cat) {   
                    echo('<option value="'.$cat[0].'">'.$cat[1].'</option>');   
                }
            echo '</select>';
            echo 'Choose a section';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($djnames, $djids, $djurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
        }
```

Code from fancount.php

```
<?php
include_once("../_inc/global.php");
include_once("../_inc/dbmysql.php");
include_once("../_inc/simple.php");
    $dbz = new db();
    $sim = new simple();

    switch ($_GET['catid']) {
        case 1: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($barnames, $barids, $barurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 2: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($beachrestaurantnames, $beachrestaurantids, $beachrestauranturl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 3:
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($clubnames, $clubids, $cluburl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 4: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($clubnightnames, $clubnightids, $clubnighturl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 5: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($djnames, $djids, $djurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 6: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($hotelnames, $hotelids, $hotelurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 7: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($liveshownames, $liveshowids, $liveshowurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 8: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($restaurantnames, $restaurantids, $restauranturl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 9: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($sunsetnames, $sunsetids, $sunseturl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        case 10: 
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($villanames, $villaids, $villaurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
            break;
        default:
            echo '<div id="facebook"><div class="facebook-midcut">',showfans($djnames, $djids, $djurl),'</div><div class="l-botcut"></div></div>';
    }
?>
```

Ajax code:

---

```
function categoryAjaxData(div,str,value)
{
    var url = str+'?catid='+value;
    ajaxData(div,url);
}

function ajaxData(div,str)
    {
        xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML='<center><img src="images/loader.gif"></center>';        
        if(xmlHttp==null)
        {
            alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
            return
        }
            var url = str;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){ DescriptionstateChanged(div); };
            xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

function DescriptionstateChanged(div)
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    {
        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

I feel it in my waters that I'm almost there... Can anyone offer a solution... MarioVW, Mr Font of Knowledge - can you bestow enlightenment upon my head?

Comment: Seems like a follow up question from this -unanswered- one: [Changing the contents of a div using a dropdown, javascript and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888910/changing-the-contents-of-a-div-using-a-dropdown-javascript-and-php)... I believe you should follow up in that same question instead of asking a new one...

Comment: I didn't want to delete the code from the last question as I thought the code in this question is sufficiently different.

Comment: Just make sure to cross-link both questions for future reference, and also accept an answer on both questions once your problem is solved.

Comment: I will do :) Sorry am new! Just learning protocol at the moment! I have am just updating the code in this question now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this question is a follow-up to [Changing the contents of a div using a dropdown, javascript and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888910/changing-the-contents-of-a-div-using-a-dropdown-javascript-and-php)

That being said, you just need to pass the variable as a GET parameter in your AJAX request, which it seems you are already doing (see `categoryAjaxData()` in the other question). Create a new PHP script with basically just the `switch` statement (and any other setup code), but instead of using `$_POST['fandropdown']` use `$_GET['catid']`.

Comment: To troubleshoot this, add `alert(div)` and `alert(xmlHttp.responseText)` inside `DescriptionstateChanged()` (outside the `if` statement).

Answer (score 0):

WHile not an expert in it, sounds like a job for AJAX

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want arrays.

showfans($names[$_POST['selectname'...

Comment: I don't think it is as simple as that? Or perhaps it is? Depending on what value of the select dropdown you choose, I want to pass 3 different variables to a function. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are the variables' (djnames,clubnames) values known before the user session. Can you edit your question to show how the values are assigned? Does your php work today for one set, like DJ's?