# How to change content in div, based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I load my content from my `DB` with `PHP`, into my div.

I have a `dropdown` above it, where i should be able to sort out the content, meaning that when `dropdown` is chosen, the old content in the `div` is removed, and the new appears.

So how is it possible to "remove" the old content in the `div`, and get the new content based on the `dropdown selection` ?

This is what i got so far:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs top_nav">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="inactive">

              <!-- THE DROPDOWN THAT SHOULD SORT THE CONTENT BELOW -->
              <!-- REMOVE OLD, AND GET NEW AFTER SELECTED -->

                <select id="filter_type">
                    <option selected value="Alle">Alle</option>
                    <option value="Privat_Tale">Privat Tale</option>
                    <option value="Erhverv_Tale">Erhverv Tale</option>
                    <option value="Gamle">Gamle</option>
                    <option value="Privat_MBB">Privat MBB</option>
                    <option value="Erhverv_MBB">Erhverv MBB</option>
                    <option value="Familietele">Familietele</option>
                    <option value="Retention">Retention</option>
                </select>
            </li>
          </ul>

  <!-- LOAD THE CONTENT FROM DB, AND SHOW IT -->

            <div class="abo_load" id="abo_load">
            <?php
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_select_edit) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_select_edit)) {
?>
        <div class="abo_box" id="abo_box">
         <label class="abo_navn"><?php echo $row['abo_name']; ?></label>
         <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['category']; ?>" name="category" />
         <form action="conn/delete.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];
?>" name="slet">
          <input class="delete" value="Delete" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Er du sikker??\nDet ville jo være ÆV med en Fejl 40!');">
         </form>
         <label class="edit">Edit</label>
         <?php include("files/edit_list_content.php"); ?>                                                       
       </div>                            
      <?php
    }
}
?>
            </div>
      </div>
```

**EDIT:**
I have already made it with JQuery, i load a php page, that gets the selected item, and then get the data from the DB. But the problem is, that when its loaded, i can't use any JQuery to manipulate with the new content. Like i have a edit label on the content with a JQuery hide function on. That function is working when i get the data though php from my DB, but not when i get the data though JQuery load. Thats why i want to load the data though php

Comment: Javascript or jQuery library might be able to help you. `onChange()`

Comment: yes it is posible eg ajax or oldschool onchange submit each time

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888910/changing-the-contents-of-a-div-using-a-dropdown-javascript-and-php?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change content of a div using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186041/change-content-of-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: i find your question a bit unclear... you are posting and re-loading your page anyway. You are getting your content with PHP. so, all you need is to print/echo the result?

Comment: I have already made it with JQuery, i load a php page, that gets the selected item, and then get the data from the DB. But the problem is, that when its loaded, i can't use any JQuery to manipulate with the new content. Like i have a edit label on the content with a JQuery hide function on. That function is working when i get the data though php from my DB, but not when i get the data though JQuery load. Thats why i want to load the data though php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind `change` event on your dropdown & based upon selection, fire an ajax request to get related content & then upon receiving update content inside `DIV`.

If you are using jQuery, Some useful functions would be:

Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Binding event: https://api.jquery.com/change/

A good example of implementation has been given here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910803/2004910

Comment: Thanks. Found out though one of the links, that it was my load() that was the problem. I needed to set the functions in the callback to get it to work. So it's all working just fine now.